# Updating master when git pointing to local

Tags: git, github

I am very very new to Git and I thought I kinda understood Git until I hit yet another wall.

I am not even sure if I am asking the right question yet but please bear with me or guide me. Here is what I have right now:

1. Pulled in a Master branch from a Git repo
2. Made some changes
3. Create a new 'temp' branch and committed my changes to it and pushed it for code review (didn't merge with Master). Git branch --list now shows me pointing to the 'temp' branch currently.
4. Tried starting a code related service and it pulled in the latest dependencies which led to compilation errors in my IDE for my project (was previously running)

Here are my questions:

1. I want to do a git pull on just master. Right now git is pointing to my local repository and I am afraid if I do a 'git pull' it'll overwrite my changes. Is there a way for me to change my branch to master and update it without losing my changes?
2. Once I am able to switch to Master and pull the latest, I presume the new code will work (except my changes won't be there). To include my changes which were already in code-review, would I need to re-do everything in Master and commit again? I am lost with respect to the workflow here. Is it just bad practice to have a local branch while Master is constantly changing and having to refactor your work?

I am sure there is a disconnect in my understanding so would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Q1
To checkout master branch, do `git checkout master`(before checkout master, you can run`git status` on temp branch to make sure your workspace is clean). Once on master branch, you can do a `git pull` to get the latest change of master on server side into you local repo.

For Q2
While you can manually apply all the change on master one by one, you shouldn't do that. Because that will change the commit it of you local changes on temp branch which may led the code review system take them as total new commit(through the diffs are completely same).
If you just want to know what it would like if combine latest master change and local temp branch. You can:
`git checkout temp`
`git checkout -b temp_with_master` # create a new test branch from temp
`git merge master` # merge master's change
make fun
`git checkout temp`
`git branch -d temp_with_master` # finally, delete test branch

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the problem correctly. When your changes are only on your local temp branch there should be no problem in pulling master.

Change to master branch with

```
git checkout master
```

and pull just master

```
git pull origin master
```

(if it's not origin, look at git remote -v)

The changes in your other branch will not be lost. Git won't let you change the branch until you've committed or stashed your changes anyway.

For commits I recommend

```
git citool
```

If you don't already use it.

There is no problem in having a local branch while the master branch is changing constantly. Although if it is changing constantly I would call it develop, not master. But that may depend...

You don't need to redo everything in master. What you need is a git merge.

change to master branch with git checkout master and merge your local temp in it.

```
git merge master temp
```

That may result in conflicts - which you then have to resolve - if someone changed the same lines that you've changed. But you will be told that by git.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think the big piece I was missing was "Git checkout master". Having done that I was able to exclusively update the Master and then I ran into a different set of problems.

Also, thanks for the various strategies all of you have mentioned. I will have to give these a whirl to better understand the approach that will fit my needs. Appreciate the thorough responses!

Answer (score 0):

For 1.) Yes, this is possible. If you have uncommitted changes that you are still working on, just go ahead and commit them before making changes (such as updating other branches). You can always come back to your 'temp' branch again later, and even "amend" it with more changes if you weren't done. (git stash is also a command many find useful for this purpose). So, what you're asking for would go like this:

```
> git commit -a -m "stashing my changes"
> git checkout master
> git pull origin
> git checkout temp
```

You have then updated master with the latest changes from 'origin' (which is the default name for the remote server) into the master branch, and you are back on temp with all your changes intact.

Answering 2.) depends a little on the workflow established by the project itself. The two options are merge and rebase, and it gets confusing explaining the pros and cons of each.

If the review isn't very important (just that the feature works, passes tests, etc) then it is simpler for some people to merge master into temp (sometimes several times over the development of the feature in your branch) and when it's ready, request that the branch get merged back into master. This is somewhat similar to an SVN workflow, where you periodically update your working tree, and only commit at the end when it's done. However, you will have a lot more commits in this case with git, as each merge is recorded, and it becomes harder to review all the changes.

```
(hack, hack, hack, commit to temp)
> git fetch origin
> git merge origin/master
(resolve merge conflicts)
```

The second option is rebase, which is where you redo all your changes on top of the updated version of master. Git will automate as much of this as it can, and stop when it runs into problems (which is handled the same as a merge conflict).

```
(hack, hack, hack, commit to temp)
> git checkout master
> git pull
> git checkout temp
> git rebase master
(resolve merge conflicts)
```

You can do this multiple times, too (update master, rebase on top of the new version of master). When you are done, you again request that the result be pulled into master. The advantage is that it's often easier for the project maintainer to review, the disadvantage is that it is now unrelated to the first version of 'temp' that was already reviewed but not merged.